# Issues with using/modifying a UITextField in a browser setting

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uitextfield, nsurl

As a small project to understand Cocoa/Cocoa Touch's API, I've been working on a small browser. I've managed to get a simple design going where there is are back/forward/reload buttons, the address bar itself, and a connect button (I have to figure out at another point how to modify the keyboard to have a "Go" button in place of the regular return.

My current problem is that my general purpose connect button's function looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)connect:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address.text]; //address is the address bar
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [address resignFirstResponder]; //kill the address entry keyboard
}
```

However, for some reason, the URL is only understood if it has 'http://' in front of it. Simply entering 'google.com' and touching the Connect button does nothing. I figure that this is either a latent issue with the NSURL class or UIWebView, but the API documentation isn't particularly helpful at times, and I simply cannot figure out which. I feel like automatically adding 'http://' to the front of the address bar's text property might be a poor idea, in case 'https://' would be needed instead (though on the other hand, a normal website often relays to a secure protocol, but this is not always the case).

I'm also having issues with the back and forward buttons in that they're not updating the address field's address. This is understandable as the address bar isn't directly tied to the WebView (perhaps there is a part of UIWebView that does this which I haven't come across?), and I haven't figured out a way to update the address bar to display the new URL. I've noted that there are UIWebViewDelegate methods which include things such as *webViewDidStartLoad*, but I'm not fully aware of how to utilize these things properly. I've tried using the *[webView isLoading]* boolean as a test, and then modify the address bar URL accordingly, but it seems to work to no avail, perhaps due to caching or something like that.

Pardon me if I haven't elaborated certain things well enough or if these questions have been answered on here already; I did a quick search and have looked around online a bit, only to fail at coming across any advice regarding what to do. As I said, Apple's API documentation, while extremely deep, is a bit awkward at times to use. If you have any more questions regarding what I'm aiming to do, I'll certainly try to answer as best I can.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL` is very picky, and will return `nil` for anything that doesn't parse as a valid URL:

From [`NSURL URLWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method documentation:

> *URLString*
>
> The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. **Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396.** This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808.

Here's a link to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

To extract the currently loaded address, you can use the [`UIWebViewDelegate webViewDidFinishLoading:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) delegate method to extract the current URL and update your text field:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    textField.text = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
}
```